# How to remove nails from concrete before putting down tile

Tags: flooring

How to remove nails from concrete. To apply tile do I need to use that underling over the nails.

Comment: Please provide a little more information.  The more information you provide about your situation the more help can be provided.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised anyone successfully used nails in concrete.

If they can't be pulled out with the normal tools, I'd grind off any protruding portion using an angle grinder or a Dremel/rotary-tool.

I believe you'd need to seal or prime the concrete before applying adhesive. You need to use a sealant that is compatible with the adhesive.

You might need to use a leveling compound before laying the tile.

Comment: They make carpet tack strips for concrete floors that use nails.  The nails are short drive about a half inch into the concrete.  Most will pop out with a pry bar but once in a while the nail head will pop off and a grinder is needed to remove it.